# local installation of Wordpress on Ubuntu 20.04 giving blank screen

Tags: apache2, directory, wordpress

I have installed Wordpress on Ubuntu 20.04 this is giving a blank screen when I use localhost/blog/wp-login.php.

apache2.conf had been edited with directories for Wordpress:

/usr/share/wordpress
/var/www/wordpress

I wish to install a local website in order to run test until I invest money on a hosting provider.

Comment: Did you install it with `sudo apt install wordpress`? Which steps did you follow?

Comment: yes, it was installed with sudo apt install wordpress. I followed the instructions in the ubuntu site; for installation; I have since gone to wordpress.org and looked at the instructions for the local installation too.